# c++ std::find custom comparator doesn't work

Tags: c++, vector, stl, find, custom-compare

I am learning how to use std::find with custom comparator now.

However, by following the guidance on-line, I am facing a compiler error.

Link to my [code](http://codepad.org/akr9cYZn).

Below is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <pair.h>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        struct comp
        {
            comp(const int& input) : _input(input) {}
            bool operator()(const pair<int, int>& iPair)
            {
                return (iPair.first == _input);
            }
            int _input;
        };

        pair<int, int> pair1(1,3);
        pair<int, int> pair2(2,4);

        vector<pair<int, int> > vec;
        vec.push_back(pair1);
        vec.push_back(pair2);

        vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp(1));
        if(it != vec.end())
        {
            cout << it->second << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Error is listed below:

```
In function 'int main()':
Line 27: error: no matching function for call to 'find(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, __gnu_norm::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, __gnu_debug_def::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, __gnu_norm::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, __gnu_debug_def::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > >, main()::comp)'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to use `find_if`?

Comment: "because why would I even read the documentation, when there's Stack Overflow?"

Comment: As well as changing `find` to `find_if` you should make `comp::operator()` const

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. I tried find_if as well which did work either. Below is the link of another try. codepad.org/0tWt79uY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::find` doesn't take a custom comparator. You need to use `std::find_if`:

```
auto it = find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp(1));
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. I tried find_if as well which did work either. Below is the link of another try. http://codepad.org/0tWt79uY

Comment: It [works on ideone](https://ideone.com/35T9fp)

Comment: Many thanks. It looks like it is a compiler issue. If I change compiler to c++ 4.9.2, I will get same error on ideone. https://ideone.com/TYjTJW

Comment: @jiyi It'll work in ideone if you place the struct comp definition outside of main()